# How to Create dependent DropdownButton with a list of nested JSON data in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I need to display the banks in dropdown button and when the bank is selected, the corresponding branches should be displayed in another dropdown button

At the moment i am only able to display the banks in the dropdown

Below is the code that i am working on

**Jason Data**

This data is coming from an api

```
{"bnks": [
        {
            "cod": "02",
            "nam": "Barclays Bank",
            "branches": [
                {
                    "cod": "2101",
                    "nam": "Barclays Headoffice Harare"
                },
                {
                    "cod": "2322",
                    "nam": "Barclays Jason Moyo Byo"
                },
                {
                    "cod": "2545",
                    "nam": "Barclays Mhangura"
                },
                {
                    "cod": "2539",
                    "nam": "Barclays Redcliff"
                }
                
            ]
        },
         {
            "cod": "14",
            "nam": "Trust Bank",
            "branches": [
                {
                    "cod": "14102",
                    "nam": "Trust Bank Eastgate"
                },
                {
                    "cod": "14103",
                    "nam": "Trust Bank Royal Mutual"
                },
                {
                    "cod": "14301",
                    "nam": "Trust Bank Byo Centre"
                },
                {
                    "cod": "14502",
                    "nam": "Trust Bank Mutare"
                },
                {
                    "cod": "14503",
                    "nam": "Trust Bank Kwekwe"
                },
                {
                    "cod": "14504",
                    "nam": "Trust Bank Gweru"
                }
            ]
        },
        ]
        }
```

**Model**

```
class ValidationDataObjectModel {
  ValidationDataObjectModel({

    required this.bnks,
  });

  late final List<Bnks> bnks;

  ValidationDataObjectModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {

    bnks = List.from(json['bnks']).map((e) => Bnks.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {

    _data['bnks'] = bnks.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
    return _data;
  }
}


class Bnks {
  Bnks({
    required this.cod,
    required this.nam,
    required this.branches,
  });
  late final String cod;
  late final String nam;
  late final List<Branches> branches;

  Bnks.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    cod = json['cod'];
    nam = json['nam'];
    branches =
        List.from(json['branches']).map((e) => Branches.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['cod'] = cod;
    _data['nam'] = nam;
    _data['branches'] = branches.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Branches {
  Branches({
    required this.cod,
    required this.nam,
  });
  late final String cod;
  late final String nam;

  Branches.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    cod = json['cod'];
    nam = json['nam'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['cod'] = cod;
    _data['nam'] = nam;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:wagma/models/banking_details_model.dart';

import 'package:wagma/utils/api_endpoints.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class BankingDetailsController extends GetxController {
  final Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var url = Uri.parse(ApiEndPoints.baseUrl + ApiEndPoints.authEndpoints.vdo);
  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };

//final String? bpn = _prefs.getString('bpn');

  getVdo() async {
    final SharedPreferences? prefs = await _prefs;

    var bpn = prefs?.getString('bpn');
    var email = prefs?.getString('semail');
    var authCode = prefs?.getString('sauthCode');

    var url = Uri.parse(ApiEndPoints.baseUrl + ApiEndPoints.authEndpoints.vdo);

    Map body = {
      "header": {"bpn": bpn, "email": email, "autCod": authCode}
    };
    http.Response vodResponse =
        await http.post(url, body: jsonEncode(body), headers: headers);

    print(vodResponse.statusCode);

    if (vodResponse.statusCode == 200) {
      // ValidationDataObjectModel data1 =
      //     ValidationDataObjectModel.fromJson(jsonDecode("[" + vodResponse.body + "]"));

      ValidationDataObjectModel data1 =
          ValidationDataObjectModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(vodResponse.body));

      // print(data);
      print('end data');
      return data1;
    } else {
      throw jsonDecode(vodResponse.body)["Message"] ?? "Unknown Error Occured";
    }

    try {} catch (error) {
      Get.back();
      showDialog(
          context: Get.context!,
          builder: (context) {
            return SimpleDialog(
              title: const Text('Error'),
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              children: [Text(error.toString())],
            );
          });
    }
  }
}
```

**Displaying page**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:wagma/controllers/banking_details_controller.dart';
import 'package:wagma/models/banking_details_model.dart';
import 'package:wagma/utils/constants.dart';
import 'package:wagma/utils/nav_bar/nav_bar.dart';

import 'package:wagma/widgets/dynamic_list_object.dart';

class BankingDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  const BankingDetails({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BankingDetails> createState() => _BankingDetailsState();
}

class _BankingDetailsState extends State<BankingDetails> {
  final BankingDetailsController bankingDetails =
      Get.put(BankingDetailsController());
  List<Bnks> bankList = [];
  //List<dynamic> bankCodeList = [];
  List<Branches> branchList = [];

  List<Branches> tempList = [];

  String? bankName;
  // String? bankCode;
  String? branchName;

  var isLoading = true;

  populateDropDowns() async {
    final ValidationDataObjectModel data = await bankingDetails.getVdo();
    setState(() {
      bankList = data.bnks;
      branchList = data.bnks.cast<Branches>();
      isLoading = false;
      print('bank list');

      print(bankList.toList());
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    populateDropDowns();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController accountNumberTextEditingController =
        TextEditingController();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Banking details'),
        backgroundColor: myDarkGreen,
      ),
      drawer: const NavBar(),
      body:

          // isLoading
          //     ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
          //     :

          Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 20, right: 20),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: ButtonTheme(
                          alignedDropdown: true,
                          child: DropdownButton<String>(
                              value: bankName,
                              iconSize: 30,
                              icon: (null),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black54,
                                fontSize: 16,
                              ),
                              hint: Text('Select Bank'),
                              onChanged: (newValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  branchName = null;
                                  bankName = newValue.toString();

                                  tempList = branchList
                                      .where((element) =>
                                          element.nam == bankName.toString())
                                      .toList();
                                  print('tempList');
                                  print(bankName.toString());
                                  print(tempList.toList());

                                  // tempList = bankList.where((element) =>
                                  //     element.nam.toString() ==
                                  //     bankName.toString());
                                });
                              },
                              items: bankList.map((e) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem(
                                  value: e.cod.toString(),
                                  child: Text(e.nam),
                                );
                              }).toList()),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                    child: DynamicListObject(
                        txtController: accountNumberTextEditingController,
                        hintText: 'Bank Code',
                        labelText: 'Bank Code',
                        fieldType: 'text'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                      child: ButtonTheme(
                        alignedDropdown: true,
                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                            value: branchName,
                            iconSize: 30,
                            icon: (null),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              fontSize: 16,
                            ),
                            hint: Text('Select Branch'),
                            onChanged: (newValue) {
                              setState(() {
                                // bankCode = null;
                                branchName = newValue.toString();
                              });
                            },
                            items: tempList.map((e) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem(
                                value: e.nam.toString(),
                                child: Text(e.nam),
                              );
                            }).toList()),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
              SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                child: DynamicListObject(
                    txtController: accountNumberTextEditingController,
                    hintText: 'Branch Code',
                    labelText: 'Branch Code',
                    fieldType: 'text'),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              DynamicListObject(
                  txtController: accountNumberTextEditingController,
                  hintText: 'Account Number',
                  labelText: 'Account Number',
                  fieldType: 'text'),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                      child: FormBuilderDropdown(
                        name: 'office_code',
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Office Code',
                          fillColor: Colors.white,
                          filled: true,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          ),
                          helperText: 'Prefered office for fees payment',
                        ),
                        items: [],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4,
                    child: FormBuilderTextField(
                      name: 'office',
                      // initialValue: 'Name',
                      readOnly: true,
                      maxLines: 1,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Office for Fees Payment',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text("Add Banking Details"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Get.toNamed('/ZimraOffices');
        },
        tooltip: 'Click here to continue',
        child: const Icon(Icons.send_rounded),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```